# Custom shipping method error: Please specify a shipping method

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have a variety of custom shipping methods in my store, but I noticed that, if the user is logged in, the order cannot be finished. The user chooses which shipping method they want and then they cannot pass the payment method, because it keeps giving this error: `Please specify a shipping method`.

Here's my code:

Model/Carrier/CustomShipping.php

```
<?php

namespace Magenticians\Moduleshipping\Model\Carrier;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Config;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Customshipping extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{

/**

* Carrier's code
*
* @var string
*/

protected $_code = 'magenticians_moduleshipping';
/**
* Whether this carrier has fixed rates calculation
*
* @var bool
*/

protected $_isFixed = true;
/**
* @var ResultFactory
*/

protected $_rateResultFactory;
/**
* @var MethodFactory
*/

protected $_rateMethodFactory;
/**
* @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
* @param ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
* @param LoggerInterface $logger
* @param ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
* @param MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
* @param array $data
*/

public function __construct(
ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
LoggerInterface $logger,
ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
array $data = []
) {

$this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
$this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
}

/**
* Generates list of allowed carrier's shipping methods
* Displays on cart price rules page
*
* @return array
* @api
*/

public function getAllowedMethods()
{
return [$this->getCarrierCode() => __($this->getConfigData('name'))];
}
/**
* Collect and get rates for storefront
*
* @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
* @param RateRequest $request
* @return DataObject|bool|null
* @api
*/

public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
/**
* Make sure that Shipping method is enabled
*/
if (!$this->isActive()) {
return false;
}
$weight = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems())
    {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item)
        {
            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren())
            {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child)
                {
                    if (! $child->getProduct()->isVirtual())
                    {
                        $weight += $child->getWeight();
                    }
                }
            } else
            {

                $weight += $item->getWeight();
            }
        }
    }
$final_weight = $weight;
/** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
$result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
$shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
$method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
/**
* Set carrier's method data
*/
$method->setCarrier($this->getCarrierCode());
$method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
/**
* Displayed as shipping method under Carrier
*/

$method->setMethod($this->getCarrierCode());
$method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
$method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
$method->setCost($shippingPrice);
if($final_weight <= 2) {
$result->append($method);
}
return $result;
}
}
```

Can't seem to find a reason why, I compared my code with others and they look pretty much identical.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems magento 2.2 is not loving underscore on attribute $_code.

```
$_code = 'magenticians_moduleshipping';
```

Try change to

```
protected $_code = 'magenticiansmoduleshipping';
```

Comment: anybody found the solution for the above problem?